# Multi-row insert in many to many relationship in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query

I have got three below tables:

```
create table r_users(id int primary key, name varchar(30));
create table r_codes(id int primary key, name varchar(10));
create table user_code
(
user_id int, 
code_id int,
constraint pk_user_code primary key(user_id, code_id),
constraint fk_user foreign key(user_id) references r_users(id),
constraint fk_code foreign key(code_id) references r_codes(id)
)
```

Now I have some users and codes in the tables:

```
insert into r_users values(1, 'John'), (2, 'Roy'), (3, 'Sam'), (4, 'Lewis');
insert into r_codes values(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D'), (5, 'K');
```

Now I want to insert the codes `A, B, C, K` to users `John, Roy and Lewis` such that the mentioned codes are inserted for each of the mentioned users as below:
The desired result is:

```
user_id | code_id
1       |     1
1       |     2
1       |     3
1       |     5
2       |     1
2       |     2
2       |     3
2       |     5
4       |     1
4       |     2
4       |     3
4       |     5
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a Cartesian product using a LATERAL JOIN.

Have a look at [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.10.2).

> ```
> select u.id, c.id
> from   r_users u
> left join lateral (select id from r_codes where id in (1, 2, 3, 5)) c on true
> where  u.id in (1,2,4);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | id
> -: | -:
>  1 |  1
>  1 |  2
>  1 |  3
>  1 |  5
>  2 |  1
>  2 |  2
>  2 |  3
>  2 |  5
>  4 |  1
>  4 |  2
>  4 |  3
>  4 |  5
> ```

> ```
> insert into user_code
> select u.id, c.id
> from   r_users u
> left join lateral (select id from r_codes where id in (1, 2, 3, 5)) c on true
> where  u.id in (1,2,4);
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from user_code;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | code_id
> ------: | ------:
>       1 |       1
>       1 |       2
>       1 |       3
>       1 |       5
>       2 |       1
>       2 |       2
>       2 |       3
>       2 |       5
>       4 |       1
>       4 |       2
>       4 |       3
>       4 |       5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8bf2505511bf950536511478477a1e98)*

As [@Lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart) has pointed out, in this case you can get the same result by using left join.

> ```
> insert into user_code
> select    u.id, c.id
> from      r_users u
> left join r_codes c
> on        c.id in (1, 2, 3, 5)
> where     u.id in (1,2,4);
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from user_code;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | code_id
> ------: | ------:
>       1 |       1
>       1 |       2
>       1 |       3
>       1 |       5
>       2 |       1
>       2 |       2
>       2 |       3
>       2 |       5
>       4 |       1
>       4 |       2
>       4 |       3
>       4 |       5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cae6885cffef825d92834fd548a14fba)*

Comment: @Lennart basically a cross join

Comment: @Lennart yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the cartesian product. In SQL lingo this is a cross join:

```
select u.id, c.y
from   r_users u
cross join (values (1), (2), (3), (5)) c (y) 
where  u.id in (1,2,4);
```

Since you know that users 1,2,4 exists you can simplify it a bit:

```
select a.x, b.y
from  (values (1), (2), (4)) a(x)
cross join (values (1), (2), (3), (5)) b(y);
```

All and all:

```
insert into user_code (user_id, code_id)
select a.user_id, b.code_id
from  (values (1), (2), (4)) a(user_id)
cross join (values (1), (2), (3), (5)) b(code_id);
```